# PHP Mail Error "not supported calendar message.ics" iCal

Tags: php, phpmailer, icalendar

I'm sending this ical as part of a multi/part email message. However I'm getting an error in outlook "not supported calendar message.ics" I have confirmed I have both a Attendee and an Organizer so I dont know why this would be happening.

```
 $ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
    'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
    'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
    'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
    'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
    'TZID:Central Time' . "\r\n" .
    'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
    'DTSTART:20141101T020000' . "\r\n" .
    'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
    'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
    'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
    'DTSTART:20090301T020000' . "\r\n" .
    'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
    'TZOFFSETFROM:-0500' . "\r\n" .
    'TZOFFSETTO:-0400' . "\r\n" .
    'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
    'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
    'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .  
    'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
    'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$rep.'":MAILTO:'.$repemail. "\r\n" .
    'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
    'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
    'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
    'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
    'DTSTART;TZID="Central Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
    'DTEND;TZID="Central Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
    'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
    'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
    'DESCRIPTION: '.$description. "\r\n" .
    'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
    'LOCATION:' . $location . "\r\n" .
    'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
    'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
    'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
    'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
    'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
    'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
    'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
    'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
    'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";

    // Send Appointment .ical file
    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="message.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
     $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $message .= $ical;
```

Comment: http://www.julian-young.com/2009/07/07/php-ical-email

Comment: You know that PHPMailer bundles an ICS generating class in the extras folder? It's pretty simple, but it does work - output is much simpler than what you've posted. That said, note [this ticket](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/175) - support for ICS is actually quite tricky.

Comment: It would help to see the resulting icalendar stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dealing with the outlook sniffer, the task that processes invitations on arrival. It's ridiculously picky and there's no documentation. Start by checking your Icalendar in the online validators. Then, send an invitation from gmail to Outlook. Use Gmail "show original" to inspect the generated Icalendar. Change your application to match exactly the gmail invitation, including the order of fields, and you should find your invitation is correctly processed by Outlook.

Comment: I personally had issues with blank Attendee line(s), but Gmail version provided a good working point to compare to